# When entity is internal, lazy loading does not work

Tags: c#, entity-framework

It is possible to force entity framework to Lazy loading collection when entity class is internal? All code is written in code first and fluent API. I have situation like this:

```
internal class Order
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Operation> Operations { get; set; }
}

internal class Operation
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int OrderId { get; set; }
   public Order Order { get; set; }
}

internal MyContext : DbContext
{
   internal DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
   internal DbSet<Operation> Operations { get; set; }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Operation>().HasRequired(x => x.Order)
                                       .WithMany(x => x.Operations)
                                       .HasForeignKey(x=>x.OrderId);
   }
}
```

And I can't figure out why entity framework doesn't lazy loading Operations Collection. I have  lazy loading true in context. It is possible to manage this?

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid that is not possible, `public` classes is a requirement for EF to create proxy classes and to enable lazy loading. Take a look this [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info:

> A custom data class must be declared with public access.

Comment: So that's it? Any walkaround in this topic? I don't understand why EF team do this right that.

Comment: Because you are defining your entities model in you custom assembly, EF surely use reflection to get your model classes and create the proxy classes which are who enable lazy loading, it's like a wrapper of your classes(inherit from your entities), that's why it needs to be `public`

Comment: So maybe I need to give InternalVisibleTo EntityFramework?

Comment: Sorry but I'm afraid that doesn't exist :)

Comment: EF4 had no problem with lazy loading for `internal` classes (for db first); but suddenly EF6 requires `public`. This is very disappointing.